# Laravel Webhook does not work as it should with the Mollie API

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

What is the best way to do that, how can you do that?

I currently have a livewire component with laravel (livewire) which renders a view. Now the problem is I have an order function there that gives mollie data and returns with a redirect to the corresponding mollie route to pay. There I have set the webhook for mollie see here.

```
public function order() {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $payment = Mollie::api()->payments()->create([
            'amount' => [
                'currency' => 'EUR',
                'value' => number_format($this->service->price, 2, '.', '')
            ],
            'description' => 'Order #' . Str::random(6),
            'redirectUrl' => route('service.order.callback'),
            'webhookUrl' => route('service.order.webhook'),
            'metadata' => [
                'user' => [
                    'id' => $user->id,
                    'name' => $user->name,
                ],
                'invoice' => [
                    'id' => 0
                ]
            ]
        ]);

        return $this->redirect($payment->getCheckoutUrl(), 303);
    }
```

Now I have adapted the route. webhook in my web.php see here...

```
Route::post('/service/order/webhook', [\App\Http\Controllers\Payment\Invoice::class, 'webhook'])->name('service.order.webhook');
```

Now it knows on a normal Laravel (php) controller further since I can take in livewire no functions simply so.

But the webhook function is not called at all and no error is spat out. The webhook function has an Invoice Database Migration and then actually puts something into the database. See here:

```
    public function webhook() {
        $invoiceUser = \App\Models\Payment\Invoice::create([
            'status' => 'paid',
            'number' => '1',
            'date' => Carbon::now(),
            'billing_detail_id' => 1,
            'payment_id' => 1
        ]);
    }
```

I just tested the whole thing on a test route and the create invoice works.

Comment: _"Now it knows on a normal Laravel (php) controller further since I can take in livewire no functions simply so."_ - those are certainly all words ... Yet I can't manage to make _any_ sense of them as a sentence.

Comment: I meant that I forward on a normal laravel controller. And not on a livewire component function

Answer (score 0):

Remember: Laravel POST routes by default are protected with the VerifyCsrfToken middleware (app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php).The webhook call is a POST request. But not from a form. So one has to define an exception. Open app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php. Add your webhook url to the protected $except array.